# Regularize for a bang-bang control

Tags: convex-optimization, disciplined-convex-programming

I have an optimal control problem with a state vector $\vec x$ and a control vector $\vec u\in[0,1]$.

If I were solving the problem without regularization I would write
$$
\min \lVert \vec x \rVert
$$
But this results in messy values for $\vec u$.

I have strong priors that $\vec u$ is bang-bang, so what I would like to do is to have
$$
\min \lVert \vec x \rVert + \lambda f(\vec u)
$$
where $\lambda$ is the strength of the regularization and $f$ penalizes $\vec u$ if it takes values other than $0$ and $1$.

One possibility is
$$
\min \lVert \vec x \rVert - \lambda \lVert \vec u - \vec 1 \cdot 0.5\rVert
$$
here $\lambda \lVert \vec u - \vec 1 \cdot 0.5\rVert$ takes large values if $\vec u$ is near 0 or 1. By subtracting this term, we create an objective that encourages such values.

Unfortunately, in so doing we create an objective that's non-convex, at least from a [disciplined convex programming](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html) perspective.

Is there another objective that will encourage bang-bang behaviours or a way to convexify this objective?

Comment: What about changing the control vector to a vector of binary variables ($u_i \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace \,\forall i$) and solving it as a (convex) binary optimization problem?

Comment: @prubin: I could do this as a backup, but the number of variables is quite large, so preserving the speed of a convex solution would be nice.

Comment: Depending on the ODE/PDE describing your state $x$, you could try utilizing the so-called *Combinatorial Integral Approximation Problem* (CIAP). Here, you solve the discretized OCP with $u \in [0,1]$ to obtain a control $u^* \in [0,1]$ and then construct a binary control $\tilde{u} \in \{0,1\}$ by solving the CIAP. This approach can also be used inside a MIP heuristic to quickly find good solutions when solving the binary optimization problem as prubin suggested.